# Wait for notification async call

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to get the lync presence status of a given user. My code will talk to lync server 2010 using UCMA 4.0 in 64 bit env.

here is my code to wait for an async call to get the lync status.

```
private async void getNotifications(UserEndpoint endpoint, string useridSIP)
{
    _userEndpoint.PresenceServices.BeginPresenceQuery(
        new[] { useridSIP },
        new[] { "state" },
        null,
        (ar) => {
            Task<List<RemotePresentityNotification>> notificationFetch = _userEndpoint.PresenceServices.EndPresenceQuery(ar).ToList<RemotePresentityNotification>();
            List<RemotePresentityNotification> result = await notificationFetch;
            result.ForEach(x => {
                LyncUser user = new LyncUser();
                if (x.AggregatedPresenceState != null)
                {
                    user.Presence = x.AggregatedPresenceState.Availability.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    user.Presence = "Unknown";
                }
                user.UserName = x.PresentityUri.ToString();
                usersWithStatus.Add(user);
            });
        },
        null);
}
```

I am not sure how to wait till the `List<RemotePresentityNotification>` results are returned

```
Task<List<RemotePresentityNotification>> notificationFetch = _userEndpoint.PresenceServices.EndPresenceQuery(ar).ToList<RemotePresentityNotification>();
List<RemotePresentityNotification> result = await notificationFetch;
```

The entire source code.

```
using Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration;
using Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.Presence;
using Oobe.Bobs.Lync.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
{
    public class OneTimePresence
    {
        private UCMASampleHelper _helper;
        private UserEndpoint _userEndpoint;
        public List<LyncUser> usersWithStatus = new List<LyncUser>();
        public LyncPresenceChecker _checker { get; set; }
        public OneTimePresence(string useridSIP, LyncPresenceChecker checker)
        {
            _checker = checker;
            _helper = new UCMASampleHelper();
            string endpoint = String.Format("OneTime Presence query for {0}", useridSIP);
            _userEndpoint = _helper.CreateEstablishedUserEndpoint(endpoint);
            getNotifications(_userEndpoint, useridSIP);
            _helper.ShutdownPlatform();

        }
        protected void EndgetNotification(object sender, RemotePresentitiesNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Notifications.ToList<RemotePresentityNotification>().ForEach(x =>
            {
                LyncUser user = new LyncUser();
                if (x.AggregatedPresenceState != null)
                {
                    user.Presence = x.AggregatedPresenceState.Availability.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    user.Presence = "Unknown";
                }
                user.UserName = x.PresentityUri.ToString();
                usersWithStatus.Add(user);
            });
            _checker.Clients.All.updateLyncUserPresence(usersWithStatus);

        }

        private void getNotifications(UserEndpoint endpoint, string useridSIP)
        {
            _userEndpoint.PresenceServices.BeginPresenceQuery(
                new[] { useridSIP },
                new[] { "state" },
                EndgetNotification,
                (ar) => {
                    ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                    List<RemotePresentityNotification> result = _userEndpoint.PresenceServices.EndPresenceQuery(ar).ToList<RemotePresentityNotification>();

                    result.ForEach(x =>
                    {
                        LyncUser user = new LyncUser();
                        if (x.AggregatedPresenceState != null)
                        {
                            user.Presence = x.AggregatedPresenceState.Availability.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            user.Presence = "Unknown";
                        }
                        user.UserName = x.PresentityUri.ToString();
                        usersWithStatus.Add(user);
                    });
                },
                null);
            if (usersWithStatus.Count > 0)
            {
                _checker.Clients.All.updateLyncUserPresence(usersWithStatus);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use async void. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article for a complete explanation. Change the method signature of getNotifications to async Task. Why do you want to wait for the results?

Comment: The lync server takes time to return status hence the anonymous method is called asynchronously

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are looking for the [`Task.Factory.FromAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This method is a wrapper around the `Begin` and `End` `async` pattern -- [detailed here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423(v=vs.110).aspx). For example you'd want to do this instead:

```
private async Task<List<RemotePresentityNotification>> GetNotifications(UserEndpoint endpoint, string useridSIP)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
        _userEndpoint.PresenceServices.BeginPresenceQuery,
        _userEndpoint.PresenceServices.EndPresenceQuery,
        new[] { useridSIP },
        new[] { "state" });

   var results = await task;
   return results.ToList();
}
```

1. Avoid `async void` detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
2. Use `async` only if there is a corresponding `await`

With this in place you could then `await` it and handle it as you see fit, like so:

```
private async Task SomeCaller(UserEndpoint endpoint, string useridSIP)
{
    var list = await GetNotifications(endpoint, useridSIP);
    // ... do stuff with it
}
```

**Update 1**

Consider ensuring that the `PresenceServices` are in fact available by checking the `State` as detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd253626(v=office.13).aspx).

> As long as the endpoint’s State property is set to Established, all presence services are available to it.

Additionally, [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/dd36a856-f9a6-4152-9c91-4bcb4e9d7c02/ucma-40-how-to-presenceservicesbeginpresencequery?forum=ucmanagedsdk) might be helpful to look at.

Comment: 1. You say to omit `async` but then don't omit it. 2. This won't work, [`EndPresenceQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh366226.aspx) returns `IEnumerable<RemotePresentityNotification>`, so to get `List<T>`, you will need to call `ToList()` somewhere (just like the code in the question).

Comment: Give me all the source and I can better assist you

Comment: I'm not the OP, I don't have access to any more code than you do.

Comment: This should now be what you're looking for.